# Are DocumentDB Partitioned Collections Not Supported in Power BI?

Tags: azure, partitioning, azure-cosmosdb, powerbi

I am trying to use DocumentDB with [Partitioned Collections](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-partition-data/). This feature requires you to pass the partition key in a HTTP header which lets Azure handle all partitioning for you. When I use Partitioned Collections in Power BI I get the following error:

[image]

Is this feature not supported by Power BI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We plan to release the support for partitioned collections in the next Power BI Desktop refresh.  We push out updates frequently.  I will update this thread when we are getting close to releasing it.

Comment: Hi, Azure DocumentDB connector for Power BI supports querying data from partitioned collections.   Please download the latest version of Power BI Desktop from https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop.